# Is kernel memory pagable?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

> A page, memory page, or virtual page is a fixed-length contiguous block of virtual memory, described by a single entry in the page table.

I wamna know if kernel memory also can be pagable?

Comment: As far I know, no. In past kernel was just one (large) page, and so unpageable. I still assume kernel is just one large page. You never know if you need the page to to swapping (and kernel is not mapped on disk). Scheduler is always needed. but filesystems and devices (disk, USB, networks) could be used to save/restore page on disks.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, And how MMU would work in such case?

Comment: Normally, Just kernel know not to swap it. Kernel has various special regions (e.g. for DMA, and for driver data, which also should not be swapped (and eventually just it can be just on some physical range). But also cache should not be paged (either discard, or write to disk [as file]).

Comment: To be sure of terminology: "pageable" as "being able for paging" (so "swapeable"), or do you mean being pages (virtual-to-physical addresses?) In later case, kernel is in a page. Ev. old BIOS has no page, just pyisical address. But to call BIOS, kernel needed to exit protected mode (and so also VM=0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, e.g. on architectures with an MMU every virtual address (user space and kernel space) is translated by the MMU. There is an area where the kernel is directly mapped, i.e. the virtual address is at a fixed offset from their physical address.

When for example a system call needs to access an address in kernel space, the page table of the last process that ran is used. It does not matter which one, since the kernel space is shared between all processes and thus is the same for all.
There is one case where physical addresses are used directly and that is in the boot process before paging is enabled.
As Giacomo Catenazzi mentioned correctly in the comments, these pages are handled differently, e.g. they can not be swapped out.

There is one case where physical addresses are used directly and that is in the boot process before paging is enabled.